# How to store and stream private video content

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing

What is the best way to create an online video-on-demand service with this requirements:

- The video must be private and secure
- Analytics
- Must use a CDN
- Flash video player

What's the best solution(s) for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually extremely easy to do with a combination of an open-source player (like [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/)) and a CDN that supports [secure streaming](http://netromedia.com/services/hotlink-protection-streamsecure.aspx) (see link). Analytics is available in almost all CDNs, so that isn't really an issue (although levels of service vary). You may want to setup a Login System, or use an [open-source CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/) - but that depends on your definition of "private".